# St. Peter Speaking on Behalf of All the Apostles

Tags: apostles, peter, authority

Consider:

(1) Jesus saith to them: But whom do you say that I am? *Simon Peter answered and said: Thou art Christ, the Son of the living God.* (Matt. 16:15-16.) (Italics added.)

(2) Then Jesus said to the twelve: Will you also go away?  And Simon Peter answered him: *Lord, to whom shall we go? Thou hast the words of eternal life.* (John 6:68-69.) (Italics added.)

(3) Then Peter answering, said to Him: *Behold we have left all things, and have followed Thee: what therefore shall we have?* (Matt. 19:27.) (Italics added.)

(4) And Peter said to Him: *Lord, dost thou speak this parable to us, or likewise to all?* (Luke 12:41) (Italics added.)

(5) Now when they had heard these things, they had compunction in their heart, and said to Peter, and to the rest of the apostles: What shall we do, men and brethren?  But Peter said to them: *Do penance, and be baptized every one of you in the name of Jesus Christ, for the remission of your sins: and you shall receive the gift of the Holy Ghost.* (Acts 2:37-38.) (Italics added.)

QUESTION: Does anyone know of a complete list of occasions in the New Testament where St. Peter speaks on behalf of *all* the Apostles?

Comment: It should also be noticed that when Peter wanted to ask Jesus a sensitive question, he prompted John to ask it, not venturing forward himself. John 13:24.

Comment: @NigelJ I guess it can be said that John was "closest" to Our Lord's Heart at that moment.:)

Comment: Up to Acts 15, Peter does tend to speak first, especially see Acts 1-3.  But after Acts 15, there's no mention of Peter as "leader".  In the books he wrote, he assigns any "leader" role to the elders of Asia Minor.  FWIW

Comment: Apparently this question is not properly denominationally scoped.  I would think it would be wise to address to the question "according to those who believe that St. Peter did speak for the apostles, when did he do that"?

Answer (score 1):

It would take a while to compile a list of times in the New Testament when Peter is recorded as speaking. The problem lies in identifying when he was speaking for himself, and when he was speaking as spokesman for the other Apostles. The Bible is not always clear about this, and personal interpretation could come into any answer.

That is demonstrated by the question here, for ***it is assumed that Peter was speaking on behalf of all the Apostles when he gave that answer to Jesus in Matthew 16:15-16.*** Not everyone on this site would agree with that interpretation, for many Christians take Peter to be boldly making a personal declaration of faith. They base this on what Jesus then told Peter:

> "And Jesus answered and said unto him, 'Blessed art thou, Simon
> Barjona: for flesh and blood hath not revealed it unto thee, but my
> Father which is in heaven. And I say also unto thee, That thou art
> Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of
> hell shall not prevail against it. And I will give unto thee the keys
> of the kingdom of heaven'..." Matthew 16: 17-19 K.J.V.

Jesus said God had personally revealed that to Peter. Now, if Peter was spokesman on behalf of all the others, why did Jesus address Peter directly with regard to God revealing a truth to him personally, and also regarding the matters following? Surely Jesus would have had to say, "thou art Peter, and also you others will have the keys of the kingdom of heaven" etc.

The matter, however, is complicated by the miracle of Jesus walking on the storm-tossed waters of the Sea of Galilee during the night. This is recorded in chapter 14, and appears to have happened beforehand. ***All*** the disciples in the boat declared Jesus to be the Son of God when he and Peter got into the boat, and the storm immediately stopped. When Peter declared Jesus to be the Son of God later, he could have been speaking for the others, for he knew they had ***all*** confessed Jesus as the Son of God in the boat, once it stopped rocking.

But given Jesus' very personal remarks to Peter in chapter 16, we cannot assume that. This is what I mean by matters not being clear-cut, when Peter speaks. If there is difficulty sorting that one occasion out (in chapter 16, your example #1), then similar difficulties will be encountered if the Bible does not clearly show that Peter was speaking on behalf of the others. Sometimes he was, sometimes he wasn't, and ***other times nobody can say with certainty.***

Your examples #2, #3, and #4 ***do*** state Peter being spokesman. But your example #5, Acts 2:37-38 is ***not*** Peter including the apostles in his address. Context shows that all the apostles and the other disciples in the upper room at Pentecost had already received the gift of the Holy Spirit, for they had previously all repented and been baptised, and it was time for that promise of Christ to be fulfilled. After that miracle of grace, the multitude of Jews and proselytes in the city for Pentecost got to hear of the miracle and discovered it to be true. That was when Peter stood up in public and spoke on behalf of all the apostles (vs. 14) to preach the good news of Christ, which required those multitudes to repent and to be baptized in the name of Jesus Christ. The apostles, however, were not being addressed! And the Greek word Peter spoke was *'metanoeo'* which cannot be translated as 'do penance', for it means 'to have another mind'. It is not about taking any actions or paying money. *Those are just two details, however, which do not detract from Peter speaking to multitudes on behalf of all the apostles.* Pardon me if this strikes you as being pedantic, for your main reason for including this as an example stands.

Yet given the difficulties I have mentioned, the answer could only be those times when the record clearly states that Peter was speaking up as spokesman, on behalf of the other Apostles. All personal interpretations of such events would have to be avoided. Therefore, Matthew 16:15-16 is unlikely to be Peter speaking on behalf of all the apostles. If I come across occasions in the New Testament where Peter is clearly stated to be speaking on behalf of the other Apostles (in addition to the examples you have given), I would hope to add to this answer. Or perhaps someone else will beat me to it, in which case, they would deserve the green tick!

Comment: The question asks for instances; if you have any to offer---why not simply state them?

Comment: @Ιδιώτης  Mtthew 15:15 for starters; that should encourage the OP to take it from there, and do some homework on the rest.